# log in user right away after the user signs up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, devise-token-auth

I am using devise token authentication(devise_token_auth) for user login and signup based on token because it is only for developing an api. I need to make the user logged in soon after the user registers his/her account. How can i do it so? I have tried but could not succeed so i am here with the hope of help.

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController
  prepend_before_action :configure_permitted_parameters
    protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:id, :first_name, :last_name, :phone, :status])
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:confirm_success_url])
    end

  private

    def user_params
      params.permit.all #(:id, :email, :firstname, :lastname, :phone, :status)
    end
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # devise_for :users, controllers: { confirmations: 'confirmations' }
  mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', controllers: {
     # confirmations: 'confirmations',
      registrations: 'users/registrations',
      passwords: 'users/passwords'
  }

class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken

  def authenticate_current_user
    head :unauthorized if get_current_user.nil?
  end

  def get_current_user
    return nil unless cookies[:auth_headers]
    auth_headers = JSON.parse cookies[:auth_headers]
    puts('################################')
    puts('auth_headers', auth_headers)
    expiration_datetime = DateTime.strptime(auth_headers["expiry"], "%s")
    current_user = User.find_by(uid: auth_headers["uid"])

    if current_user &&
       current_user.tokens.has_key?(auth_headers["client"]) &&
       expiration_datetime > DateTime.now

       @current_user = current_user
    end

    @current_user
  end

end
```

I tried this below code

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      puts('it should be shown')
      puts('################################')
      puts('resource', resource)
      puts('header', request.headers['client'])
      client_id = request.headers['client']
      new_auth_header = @resource.create_new_auth_token(client_id)
      response.headers.merge!(new_auth_header)
  end
```

in the Users::RegistrationController but it is not executed at all after successfully signing up.

Answer (score 0):

Not too complicated. After creating the user, just call `sign_in` and pass the resource (user).

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Sign-in-from-a-controller

Example:

```
sign_in @current_user
```

The `Devise::RegistrationController` in fact, [already does this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/95689757c0945e15a4880919c15a55aeda118630/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L108).

Furthermore, since you're using the [`DeviseTokenAuth`](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) [`gem`](https://rubygems.org/gems/devise_token_auth) and the [`DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController` controller](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/master/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/registrations_controller.rb#L2) [inherits from `Devise`'s own base controller](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/master/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/application_controller.rb#L2), you (should) have [access to all the helpers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb#L4-L9) that `Devise` controllers do.

One [implementation might look like](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#passing-blocks-to-controllers) this.

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController
  def create
    super do |resource|
      sign_in(resource)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: so does this works when I am developing only an api from the rails?

Comment: Should i use that sign_in controller inside registration_controller(class Users::RegistrationsController) like def sign_in? or can you show me where in the code should i implement that?

Comment: @Serenity updated answer, let me know if that doesn't help!

Comment: but I am using DeviseTokenAuth(devise_token_auth gem).

Comment: @Serenity I did the footwork and `Read The Fantastic Manual` for you ;) check out the update answer!

Comment: I tried that create function but i get error RegistrationController has not create function, something like that. probably its because i have not use the super keyword.